# Typescript: get type of interface property based on interface key

Tags: javascript, typescript, strong-typing

I'm building a function that needs to update one field of an object at a time.
this object is defined through an interface `T`.

```
interface T {
  a: TypeA;
  b: TypeB;
  c: TypeC;
}
```

This should be the type signature of this function:

```
(key: keyof T, value: typeof T[key]) => void
```

This generates the error: `'key' refers to a value, but it is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof key'?`. IMO I did not mean `typeof key`, since `typeof key` would be any key of `T`, but I want the `value` attribute to be of type `TypeA` if `key = a`, etc.

How can I select the type of the corresponding key value of `T`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to index a type with a real value, and this is not allowed. You need to access it with a type ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCrIN4ChnLgLmRAFcBbAI2gG4dlzCBnMKUAcxtwUPIHseAbCHBA0AvliwIeIJshjEQCZAF5kAHgDSyCAA9IIACYNkAawgBPHjDQA%20ABRnzhDQBpkANzj9iEQqgDaGgC6AJQqNpiiNFjyinYARHDxbgCsITSxCAnkychpVMgA9IXIAIJQrGQQ4MhWyGDmAA4oAOQkFNAtyMDGIDxgeAwMwKwgcOSC9TzIjXBQcKQQkFC11g3NyC1MLCCsLQB0WEA)):

```
interface T {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: boolean;
}

const func = <K extends keyof T>(key: K, value: T[K]) => {};

func("a", 5);
func("b", 5); // Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

There is a clear distinction between types and real values in typescript since the type information is lost after transpilation. Thus you cannot use real values to define type logic. The only way would be to extract the type value of a real value (e.g., with `typeof`), which is why the compiler suggests transitioning your real value into a type.

Comment: I have run into a similar scenario:

`type MyType<T = any> = {
  key: keyof T;
  func: (valType: T[keyof T]) => void;
};`

But this in turn gives all the keys present in `T` for `valType`. How do I make sure that I get only the desired type for it interpreted from `key`?

Comment: You will need a second generic for the key: https://tsplay.dev/WJAVVm